# 401 error if I connect from my ASP.NET app. to CrmDiscoveryService.asmx (CRM 2011)

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, claims-based-identity

I have to use CrmDiscoveryService.asmx for DYNAMICS CRM 2011 because of the compatability to CRM 4.0. I impemented IFD authentification algorithm and now it doesnt works:

I can connect me successfully to CrmDiscoveryService.asmx from Browser (anonymous connection enabled)
URL: *https://internalcrm.organme>.com:444/mscrmservices/2007/spla/crmdiscoveryservice.asmx*

But if I try to get connected with the same URL from ASP.NET - i receive 401 error.
Code:

```
RetrieveCrmTicketRequest crmTicketRequest = new RetrieveCrmTicketRequest();
crmTicketRequest.OrganizationName = OrgUniqueName;
crmTicketRequest.UserId = "bnet"+"\\"+"izz";
crmTicketRequest.Password = "pass";
CrmDiscoveryService discoveryService = serviceHandler.CreateCrmDiscoveryService(crmDiscoveryServiceUrl);
discoveryService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
RetrieveCrmTicketResponse crmTicketResponse =
(RetrieveCrmTicketResponse)discoveryService.Execute(crmTicketRequest);

//Trust all certificates
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be it make sense to start from retrieving a list of available organizations, like in a sample [Using the CrmDiscoveryService Web Service: IFD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151010.aspx)

```
// Configure an instance of the CrmDiscoveryService Web service proxy.
CrmDiscoveryService disco = new CrmDiscoveryService();
disco.Url = "https://localhost/MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx";

//Retrieve a list of available organizations from the CrmDiscoveryService Web service.
RetrieveOrganizationsRequest orgRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();
// Substitute an appropriate domain, username, and password here.
orgRequest.UserId = domain + "\\" + username;
orgRequest.Password = password;
RetrieveOrganizationsResponse orgResponse = (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)disco.Execute(orgRequest);

//Find the target organization.
OrganizationDetail orgInfo = null;

foreach (OrganizationDetail orgdetail in orgResponse.OrganizationDetails)
{
    if (orgdetail.OrganizationName.Equals("AdventureWorksCycle"))
    {
        orgInfo = orgdetail;
        break;
    }
}

// Check whether a matching organization was not found. 
if (orgInfo == null)
    throw new Exception("The specified organization was not found.");

//Retrieve a CrmTicket from the CrmDiscoveryService Web service.
RetrieveCrmTicketRequest ticketRequest = new RetrieveCrmTicketRequest();
ticketRequest.OrganizationName = orgInfo.OrganizationName;
ticketRequest.UserId = domain + "\\" + username;
ticketRequest.Password = password;
RetrieveCrmTicketResponse ticketResponse =
    (RetrieveCrmTicketResponse)disco.Execute(ticketRequest);
```

Comment: thanks for assumption, but no success. I have the same error.

Comment: you can also try set user credentials in your code, but do not use 'discoveryService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;'

Answer (score 0):

As paramosh was saying, try setting the credentials on the discovery service too:

discoveryService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("izz", "password", "bnet");